# Difference amplifier using Op-amp in LT-SPICE

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, simulation, differential

I am simulating differnce amplifier in LTSPICE as shown below, i have used 400V DC source with 10V sin wave and then i am dividing it by factor of 80 and them taking differece with 5V source.
[image: LTSPICE difference amplifier Schematic]

Below are the output waveforms, the left one is at the output of opamp and the right one is the voltage between 79k and 1kohm resistors.

I have no clue why is the opamp output voltage is oscillating between ~1V to ~9Vs. Please help me is solving this problem.

[image: LTSPICE simulation plot] [image: Voltage between 79K and 1Kohm resistors]

Comment: Manish, if you are done with this question now you should formally accept an answer or add a comment requesting further clarification. [If you take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour), it'll explain why you should do this and what you need to do to accept an answer.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R6 is in the wrong place for a differential amplifier.

It should go from the op-amp non-inverting input to ground.

Where it is, it is connected across a fixed voltage so it does nothing except waste some simulated energy.

Answer (score 3):

> *I have no clue why is the opamp output voltage is oscillating between
> ~1V to ~9Vs. Please help me is solving this problem.*

Your amplifier circuit is drawn wrong as Spehro as pointed out but the reason it oscillates is because you haven't checked the data sheet to see that it can be operated in a closed loop gain of unity: -

[image]

Your circuit, should you fix the circuit error or not, will have a closed-loop gain of near enough unity and it will sing.